# <mat-form-field> <matInput> no se actualiza

Tags: javascript, html5, angular

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Quiero poder modificar el placeholder junto con el uso de una etiqueta

Esta captura muestra como es la pagina antes de apretar el boton

[image: Here's the page]

Aqui se muestra la misma pagina ya con el boton apretado, se puede ver que en la consola si me cambia 'carbonada' por 'a', pero no me la cambia en el placeholder.

[image: and here is the event of the button]

Les dejo mi codigo html y .js para que visualicen bien el problema

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
  myFunction() {
    let e =document.getElementById("dia0P0") as HTMLInputElement ;
    e.placeholder='a';
    console.log(e.placeholder) ;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <mat-form-field id="ddd">
        <input type="number" matInput #d0p0  id='dia0P0' placeholder="carbonada" >
    </mat-form-field>
   
<p>Click the button to change the placeholder text of the text field.</p>

<button (click)="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: favor de traducir tu pregunta, estas en SO en español de lo contrario terminará cerrada

Comment: Listo caballero

Comment: se me ocurre que podría ser que tienes que refrescar el elemento input, eso me ha sucedido con los select usando materialize. Otra es que uses la ventaja del data-binding y desde ahí le vayas pasando el valor del placeholder, es lo que se me ocurriría , saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando por alguna razon especifica funciones de JS vanilla?

Deberias de crear una variable en tu .ts como:

```
let placeholder = 'carbonada'
```

despues en tu funcion:

```
myFunction() {
   this.placeholder = 'a';
}
```

Y entonces en el html:

```
<input type="number" matInput #d0p0  id='dia0P0' [placeholder]="placeholder">
```